# Getting Flutter APK file

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, apk

So this is my first time trying to build Flutter apk file in Visual Studio code and on YouTube when they entered `flutter build apk --build-name:1.0.1 --build-number=2` their code worked but for me it displayed this error:

```
Target file "--build-name:1.0.1" not found.
```

Any idea how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you typed --build-name: instead of --build-name=
The build tool probably thinks you want to name the file instead of giving it instructions

Answer (score 1):

Update `version:1.0.0+1` in your `pubspec.yaml`.

1.0.0 represents the versionName

1 (the number after the +) represents the versionCode

After updating the version number in the `pubspec.yaml` file, run `flutter pub get`. This updates the versionName and versionCode in the local.properties file, which are later updated in the build.gradle file when you rebuild the Flutter app with `flutter build apk`

Also note that for every release, the version code has to be changed as well. Eg, you cannot simply change the version name from 1.0.0+1 to 1.1.0+1. It has to be changed to 1.1.0+2

Answer (score 1):

Just use
flutter build apk

1.0.1 is the build name which they defined in pubspec
You dont have to worry about that for more refer to
https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes